# mysql relationships between tables

Tags: mysql, sql, diagram

my question is:
how to build a diagram, I don't understand that many to many , or one to many and about primary key and foreign key and etc..

here is my code. is about a hospital where i have:

`NURSES`, `WARD`, `PATIENTS`, `DOCTORS`.

```
CREATE TABLE Nurses(
  `idNurses` INT NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Fname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Lname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Speciality` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idNurses`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE Doctors (
  `idDoctors` INT NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Fname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Lname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Speciality` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idDoctors`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;



CREATE TABLE Ward(
  `idWard` INT NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Location` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Nurses_idNurses` INT NOT NULL,
  `Doctors_idDoctors` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idWard`, `Nurses_idNurses`, `Doctors_idDoctors`),
  INDEX `fk_Ward_Nurses_idx` (`Nurses_idNurses` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Ward_Doctors1_idx` (`Doctors_idDoctors` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Ward_Nurses`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Nurses_idNurses`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Nurses` (`idNurses`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Ward_Doctors1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Doctors_idDoctors`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Doctors` (`idDoctors`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Patient (
  `idPatient` INT NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Fname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Lname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `DOB` DATE NULL,
  `Phone_number` INT NULL,
  `Ward_idWard` INT NOT NULL,
  `Ward_Nurses_idNurses` INT NOT NULL,
  `Ward_Doctors_idDoctors` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idPatient`, `Ward_idWard`, `Ward_Nurses_idNurses`, `Ward_Doctors_idDoctors`),
  INDEX `fk_Patient_Ward1_idx` (`Ward_idWard` ASC, `Ward_Nurses_idNurses` ASC, `Ward_Doctors_idDoctors` ASC),![enter image description here][1]
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Patient_Ward1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Ward_idWard` , `Ward_Nurses_idNurses` , `Ward_Doctors_idDoctors`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Ward` (`idWard` , `Nurses_idNurses` , `Doctors_idDoctors`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: You're asking for your work to be done for you. If you don't understand these things, go ahead and learn about them (its as simple as a google search and reading).

Comment: please i just need a bit of help please

Comment: no I just need some help i've done the diagram , i just need help to check if is it correct or not

Comment: If that's the case, then go ahead and post the diagram image so we can see what you've done. It would also be better in that case to refine the question to ask whether you've represented the model correctly, and any other concerns you have.

Comment: If you don't understand the concepts, then learn the concepts first.  There are many books and tutorials on data modeling that explain the concepts of primary keys, foreign keys, and so on.  Then do the modeling after you have some understanding of what you are doing.

Comment: I can't upload the pic,, because I don't have the 10 on my reputation to uppload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship between tables depends upon what kind of design you want to have i.e. this is something you have to decide.

1: Ward has multiple patients.
2: Patient has one ward.
3: Doctor can have multiple nurses working with them and can have multiple patients.
4: Sames with nurses along with having multiple or just one ward assigned to them.

So as you can see, there are n number of possible combinations here and no absolute solutions. Depending upon your design,come up with the database schema.